# Как перейти к самостоятельной разработке Web-приложений?

Tags: веб-программирование

Маленькая вводная:
Работаю инженером по автоматизации производства программирую на языках стандарта [МЭК 61131-3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3),
немного Arduino. В моей текущей работе "создание проекта" сводиться к выбору контроллера и написанию логики работы установки, станка, линии нужное подчеркнуть:)

Web-разработкой занялся как хобби, хочу создать свой проект аналог [LinkTree](https://linktr.ee/)
Почитав статьи начал с изучения HTML и CSS в HTML Academy
Дальше преступил к изучению JavaScript, изучал по видео курсу Владилена Минина и [Learn JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/)
Сейчас преступил к изучению React

Суть проблемы:
Не могу нечего написать самостоятельно, долго думал почему. Пришёл к выводу что не понимаю принципов построения приложения. Если объяснять на бытовом уровне, я узнал что такое цемент, кирпичи, мастерок а как с помощью этого возвести стену не знаю.

Как мне прейти к самостоятельной разработке а не копированию того что увидел в видео курсах?

Comment: попробуйте сделать что-то простое, потом что-то сложнее и так далее.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну вы например переписали код с платформы где учитесь, ага, то есть вы запомнили что то, попытайтесь это воспроизвести, добавляя что то свое, там цвет поменяю, тут элементы переставлю, вот здесь удалю, тут сделаю то что видел тогда, но вот по такой стилистике. И вот вы уже пишите что то свое. Плюс есть милен макетов для учебы, где то есть анимация, где то нет, пройдитесь по сайтам, соберите анимацию которая приглянулась, постройте в голове цепочку, как бы можно было ее воссоздать. Такими темпами и научитесь. И не бойтесь, это не цемент, не кирпич, код можно легко стереть и пробовать сначала